# Jenkins bitbucket oauth plugin - limit login to team

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I installed the Bitbucket oauth plugin on my Jenkins farm. Everything works with my key and secret key provided my BitBucket, however, I want to limit the login only to our team. As of right now, anyone with a bitbucket account can login to our Jenkins farm.

These are the steps that I took:
1. Clicked on my team, then click on 'Manage Team'
2. Under ACCESS MANAGEMENT I clicked on OAuth.
3. I added the key and secret key into Jenkins.

Now anyone with a bitbucket account can login to our Jenkins farm. However, we only want our team to login into our Jenkins farm.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. And this is how I resolved it. Your steps are correct.

> These are the steps that I took:
>   1. Clicked on my team, then click on 'Manage Team'
>   2. Under ACCESS MANAGEMENT I clicked on OAuth.
>   3. I added the key and secret key into Jenkins.

Steps to resolve this issue:
1. On Jenkins, under 'Manage Jenkins'->'Configure Global Security', enable 'Bitbucket OAuth Plugin'.
2. Next, enter your key and secret key from bitbucket, check 'Logged-in users can do anything' under authorization.
3. Click, 'Apply' and 'Save'.
4. Go back to 'Manage Jenkins'->'Configure Global Security'.
5. Enabled Matrix-based security and add each member of your team.

For some reason, you need to save you key and secret key then proceed to add your member of your group in the 'Matrix-based security'. Also, give appropriate permission to each member on the 'Matrix-based security' column.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but if you dont want to add each member .. say your team is big and has more than 100 people :)

Just create a team in bitbucket and add all the people to it.
If the team is already there , no need to do it again.

Now at Jenkins side :

- Manage Jenkins
- Configure Global Security
- Enable Security ( will be enabled already as you've setup OAuth )
- Under **Authorization**
- Matrix-based security
- Add user or group
- You will get an alert popup, enter the **teamname::member** , click ok ( note -this groups are created automatically in Jenkins by plugin w.r.t to bitbucket team structure )
- This should add the team to list in matrix, if you see a red cross against the entry it means its not a valid group.
- If you can see the group normally, then go ahed and give permission you want to grant
- Save & Apply and Have FUN !!!

---

[image: List item]